# How can I find nearby place with latitude and longitude in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Am very new to mongodb and golang. I have a collection named "myplace" It has the following fileds place_name, city, latitude, longitude. My question is user in some place and searching the nearby places. How can I query to mongodb to find near by locations. Also in golang.

My doc structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("544a2147785b707b340ed6c7"),
    "latitude" : 12.36547,
    "longitude" : 1.235689,
    "place_name" : "some_place",
    "city" : "Some city"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi can you insert doc structure and what you find ?

Comment: @yogesh I don't know how to find

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi For your case I think you should changed above doc as below

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("545749dba2b0b4cf603a7546"),
    "city" : "B",
    "placeName" : "A",
    "loc" : {
        "lon" : 51.10682735591432,
        "lat" : -114.11773681640625
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("545749f3a2b0b4cf603a7547"),
    "city" : "B1",
    "placeName" : "A1",
    "loc" : {
        "lon" : 51.09144802136697,
        "lat" : -114.11773681640625
    }
}
```

After that indexing the above documents as below

```
db.collectionName.ensureIndex({loc:"2d"})
```

If indexing executing properly then write following query to find out near by documents

```
db.location.find({loc: {$near:[51,-114]}})
```

for more help you should refer this mongo $near and $geoNear [click here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)

and sorry for golang because I don't know more about golang

for golang

```
var places []Place
lat := 51.515614
long := -0.268998
err = coll.Find(bson.M{"loc": bson.M{"$near": []float64{long, lat}, "$maxDistance" :      0.056}}).All(&places)
```

Comment: Can you please write code for golang. I tried like this    var place []Place  lat := 51.515614
 long := -0.268998
 E := 0.00002
 err = coll.Find(bson.M{"loc": bson.M{"$near": [long,lat], bson.M{"$maxDistance" : 0.056}}}).All(&place)

Comment: Sorry @sanu  golang is new for me and for learning golang for me  it takes time, maybe you should try or wait for some one who expert in golang  and convert mongo query to golang .

Comment: I think for locations on Earth you need to use 2dsphere instead of 2d

Answer (score 2):

This link might help you https://github.com/mendrugory/Airports

MongoDB query (python)

```
def get_closest_airports(lonlat, limit=10):
    """
    Using a raw query it returns the "limit" closest airports.

    :param latlon list:
    :return list of airports:
    """
    return Airport.objects(
        __raw__={"loc": {"$near": {"$geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": lonlat}}}}).limit(limit)
```

json structure is as following

```
{"city": "Goroka", "tz": "Pacific/Port_Moresby", "name": "Goroka", "dst": "U", "loc": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [145.391881, -6.081689]}, "country": "Papua New Guinea", "iata/faa": "GKA", "altitude": 5282.0, "icao": "AYGA", "timezone": 10.0, "id": 1}
```