# Best Way for Search GPS points in a NOSQL Database

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, sorting, search, gps

My questions is related on what is the best way to handle data related gps points in a database (in my case nosql DB MongoDB) in order to returns only closest points.

I have a collections of users in my database.
Now I need to create a new "table" which associate users with gps points (an user can have more points). For example:

```
User,lat,long
ALFA,40,50
ALFA,30,50
BETA,42,33
...
```

The server should makes available a function that, given a position in input, returns a list of users which are associated to points near the input.
For example:

```
function nearestUsers(lat,lon){
 var mindif = 10000;
 var closest;

 users = getAllRecordsFromDataBase(); //query for MongoDB that returnst all records of the new table

 for ( i = 0 ; i < users.length; i++){
    if(this.distance(lat,lon,users[i].lat,users[i].lon)>mindif) delete users[i];
 }

 return users;

}
```

The distance function is the following:

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  lat1 = Deg2Rad(lat1);
  lat2 = Deg2Rad(lat2);
  lon1 = Deg2Rad(lon1);
  lon2 = Deg2Rad(lon2);
  var R = 6371;
  var x = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2);
  var y = (lat2 - lat1);
  var d = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) * R;
  return d;
}
```

I'm afraid that, for big amount of data, this approch will result slow. Which is the best way to make more scalable the algorithm? Any suggestions?

Considering that this funcionality is inside my server in Node.js using a MongoDB, can I implement this function directly via query or using some special structure in my database?

Comment: Create a 2dSphere index on users lat long, and use geospatial queries to find it.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find nearby place with latitude and longitude in mongodb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710271/how-can-i-find-nearby-place-with-latitude-and-longitude-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mongodb [geospatial indexes and queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/). Just store you points as GeoJSON points and perform queries using GeoJSON polylines as bbox-es and [$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/).